# Specifying whitelist of domain names still allows others to authenticate with python social auth and django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm following along this tutorial: http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2014/04/tutorial-adding-facebooktwittergoogle-authentication-to-a-django-application/ and am specifically interested in the Google authentication. I have successfully been able to create the demo site, and am able to log in using Google.

Reading the documentation of python social auth, you should be able to specify a list of whitelist domains: http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/settings.html#whitelists

When I place `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_WHITELISTED_DOMAINS = ['foo.com']` in `settings.py` I am still able to log in using my standard gmail account. How do you limit those who can log in to only those with a `@foo.com` email?

Comment: Try ``SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_WHITELISTED_DOMAINS``

Comment: You should submit and answer, because that worked! It raised the AuthForbidden exception.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your variable name in settings is not correct, it should be:  `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_WHITELISTED_DOMAINS`

Comment: Excellent, this is what I was missing thanks @ver04ka

Comment: This works, but it still shows the other google accounts the use may have. Is there a way to limit the accounts displayed to only those they can use? As it is, they have to try before they find out they can't use those, which is a touch goofy.