# Whitelist Specific Users for Django-allauth Signup

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, python-social-auth

After django-allauth is integrated with a website, anyone can sign up by clicking the social app login or directly signing up. What shall be done to only allow specific users to sign up?

After searching through django-allauth documentation, I didn't find any configuration related. However, python-social-auth provides the WhiteList described in the question below.

[Specifying whitelist of domain names still allows others to authenticate with python social auth and django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795948/specifying-whitelist-of-domain-names-still-allows-others-to-authenticate-with-py)

Comment: Anybody knows? I am new to this whitelist stuff.

Comment: I guess some Adapter needs to be implemented in django-allauth, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113623/django-allauth-only-allow-users-from-a-specific-google-apps-domain?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by following the similar method of [django-allauth: Only allow users from a specific google apps domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113623/django-allauth-only-allow-users-from-a-specific-google-apps-domain?rq=1)

NOTE: If you turn off the local account sign up, then the social sign up has to be enabled separately!